# python ldap3 set timezone for querys

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap3

When i query an Active Directory with ldap3, the timezone for the results seem to be UTC by default.

In the docs i find a timezone module, but i can't figure out how to use it properly, so that my datetime results have an offset of -2.

https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/source/ldap3.core.html#ldap3.core.timezone.OffsetTzInfo

```
from ldap3 import Tls, Server, Connection, ALL, SUBTREE, NTLM
from ldap3.core.timezone import OffsetTzInfo
import ldap3
import ssl

server = Server('windc.company.de', use_ssl=True, get_info=ALL, connect_timeout=1),
conn = Connection(server, user=USER, password=PASSWORD, authentication=NTLM, receive_timeout=2)
conn.bind()
Path_Root = "DC=Domain,DC=company,DC=de"
Filter= "(&(objectclass=user)(&(sAMAccountName=someUseName)(!(objectclass=computer))))"
conn.search(search_base=Path_Root, search_filter=Filter, search_scope=SUBTREE, attributes = ["lastLogon"])
```

As far as I understand, the following string must be inserted into the query.

```
tzinfo=OffsetTzInfo(offset=-2, name='abc')
```